# Question on Relation closures

Tags: relations

Let R be a relation on N defined by (x, y) ∈ R iff there is a prime p such that y = px. Describe in words the reflexive, symmetric and transitive closures of R, denoted by r, s and t, respectively

> (a) Which of the following are true:
>
> > r(s(R)) = s(r(R))
> >
> > r(t(R)) = t(r(R))
> >
> > s(t(R)) = t(s(R))
>
> (b) Which of them hold for all relations on N?
>
> (c) Using the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive closures, express the smallest equivalence relation containing an arbitrary relation.
>
> (d) What is the smallest partial order containing R?

Help needed, I don't even know how to start at all!

Edit: Attempt on defining the relation
r(R)= {(x,x) ∈ NxN| There is a prime such that x=px}
s(R)={(x,y)∈ NxN| There is a prime such that y=px} v {(y,x) ∈ NxN| There is a prime such that x=py} 
t(R)= {(x,y ∈ nxN| There is a prime such that y=px}^{(y,z ∈ NxN| There is a prime such that z=yx}

Comment: Start by describing, in words, the reflexive, symmetric and transitive closures of $R$, denoted by $r, s$ and $t$, respectively .  eg:  "$\langle x,y\rangle\in r(R)$ iff…."

Comment: Hi I attempted to define, can you help me check for any sorts of error? Thanks how do you even proof for part A?

Answer (score 1):

A *closure* of $R$ is the smallest relation with the indicated property that contains $R$.

You must determine the minimum amount that needs to be added to $R$ until it has the required property.

---

Thus, $r(R)$ is the *smallest* reflexive relation on $\Bbb N$ that contains $R$, so:.$$r(R)=R\cup\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in\Bbb N\}$$

Now, describe this *in words*.

And so on.